# What is the default font size in Chrome Mobile?

Tags: css, fonts, mobile-chrome

I am trying to figure out what the default font size on Chrome Mobile is.

It's not displayed in the Chrome Mobile settings page and Googling it has proven futile. I don't have the ability to run the Chrome Remote Debugger at the moment.

Comment: https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Mobile's default font size is 16px.

Verified via remote debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You might run the following code to get `font-size` (make sure you run it before any CSS which set `font-size` to `html` was applied):

```js
alert(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('html'))['font-size'])
```